# PDO data isn't storing in db

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm going to get straight to the point. I'm building a prototype PHP app using MAMP on my localhost.

I wanted to make it so sign-up conversions are as effortless as possible for the end-user.

So for starters I'm using the fb phpsdk to fetch all the users graph data to build users profiles frictionlessly. I've got it all displaying fine.

However I'm pulling my hair out trying to get the data to successfully store using PDO. I successfully got the code to work using the $_POST method with form inputs prior to me using it to my example below.

I just don't understand why it's not working without the $_POST method. The database is setup fine, like I said I tested it and used the PDO code below.

**Storing to DB attempt using PDO**

```
require_once 'fbphpsdk/src/facebook.php'; // include the facebook php sdk
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'xxxx', // app id
        'secret' => 'xxxx')// app secret
);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) { // check if current user is authenticated
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (Exception $e) {}
}

$user = "xxxx";
$pwd = "xxxx";

$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx;", $user, $pwd);

$q = "INSERT INTO users(u_fullname, age, u_location, u_gender, u_bday, u_employer, u_job) VALUES(:u_fullname, :age, :u_location, :u_firstname, :u_gender, :u_bday, :u_employer, :u_job)";
$query = $odb->prepare($q);
$results = $query->execute(array(
        ":u_fullname" => $u_fullname,
        ":age" => $age,
        ":u_location" => $u_location,
        ":u_gender" => $u_gender,
        ":u_bday" => $u_bday,
        ":u_employer" => $u_employer,
        ":u_job" => $u_job));
```

**The fb user data (PHP)**

```
$fbuid = $user_profile['id'];
$u_employer = $user_profile['work'][0]['employer']['name'];
$u_job = $user_profile['work'][0]['position']['name'];
$u_firstname = $user_profile['first_name'];
$u_fullname = $user_profile['name'];
$u_location = $user_profile['location']['name'];
$u_gender = ucfirst($user_profile['gender']);
$u_bday = $user_profile['birthday'];

//explode the date to get month, day and year
$u_bday = explode("/", $u_bday);

//get age from date or birthdate
$age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $u_bday[0], $u_bday[1], $u_bday[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$u_bday[2])-1):(date("Y")-$u_bday[2]));?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where does `$user_profile` get populated?

Comment: I have an external php file (which is loaded via php require.) See my edit above to see the code

Comment: Assuming you're doing this locally, what do you get if you `print_r($user)`?

Comment: @AndrewSquire Your INSERTs and VALUES don't match. You have 7 INSERTS and 8 VALUES. You're missing values for `u_firstname`. Either add it to your INSERT/VALUES or delete it. And try putting a space in `VALUES(` and `users(`

Comment: I tried adding a space it didn't make a difference in storing it. Also when I run print_r($user) it prints my (or the authed user) userID

Answer (score 1):

your query is wrong, replace

you have a extra `:u_firstname` in your query

`$q = "INSERT INTO users(u_fullname, age, u_location, u_gender, u_bday, u_employer, u_job) VALUES(:u_fullname, :age, :u_location, :u_firstname, :u_gender, :u_bday, :u_employer, :u_job)";`

with

`$q = "INSERT INTO users(u_fullname, age, u_location, u_gender, u_bday, u_employer, u_job) VALUES(:u_fullname, :age, :u_location, :u_gender, :u_bday, :u_employer, :u_job)";`

Comment: fixed it, it still isn't storing :(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, it appears that the library uses `POST` by default. If you want to use a `GET` request, you have to supply the `method` parameter when you call the `api()` method. My PHP is getting pretty rusty, but I'll see if I can come up with the correct syntax you need to use...

**EDIT:**

Looks like you want something like:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api(
    '/me', 
    array('method' => 'GET')
);
```

This is untested (I don't have a test environment for PHP at the moment), but I pulled that from the tests in the project's Github page: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/tests/tests.php

Comment: Interesting. I added it to my php file, it doesn't seem to have made a difference unfortunately :(. Any other ideas? I was thinking maybe it had to do with the fact that all the fb graph data I grabbed was passed from the fb arrays to a php variable?

Comment: I've tried everything, apparently it's impossible to do.

I think my odds are better using FQL for grabbing users data.

Comment: @AndrewSquire I doubt it's impossible, but I'm unfortunately not familiar enough with the PHP library to say for sure. Looks like I asked the wrong question above; what do you get from `print_r($user_profile)`?

Comment: I just get the authenticated user id, I'm going to give FQL a whirl. Seems like it will work just as well post authentication